# How to compare multiple specific columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, similarity

I am not much experienced with [r](/questions/tagged/r), any help is appreciated. I have a dataset that is like this:

```
df <- tibble(
a = rnorm(10),
b = rnorm(10),
c = rnorm(10),
d = rnorm(10),
Adam = rnorm(10),
Aaron = rnorm(10),
Abby = rnorm(10),
Brett= rnorm(10),
Bobby= rnorm(10),
Blaine= rnorm(10),
Cate= rnorm(10),
Camila= rnorm(10),
Calvin= rnorm(10),
Dana= rnorm(10),
Debbie= rnorm(10),
Derek= rnorm(10))
```

I am trying to compute cosine [similarity](/questions/tagged/similarity) between column A and the columns with A names( Adam, Aaron, Abby) and similarly between column B and columns with B names (Brett, Bobby, Blaine) etc. I tried using `map` from [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package but cannot quite figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the dataset  into a `list` of dataset based on the first character of the column name, then loop over the `list` with `map`, do the `cosine_similarity` (from `tcR` package), between all the columns and the first column ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd' - in the `list` elements)

```
library(tcR)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
    split.default(toupper(substr(names(.), 1, 1)))   %>%
    map_dfc( ~ { nm1 <- names(.x)[1]
             .x %>%
                 summarise_at(-1, ~ cosine.similarity(!! rlang::sym(nm1), .))})
# A tibble: 1 x 12
#    Adam Aaron  Abby    Brett   Bobby  Blaine  Cate Camila Calvin  Dana  Debbie   Derek
#*   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 -0.0444 0.110 0.356 -0.00975 -0.0277 -0.0297 0.270 -0.222 -0.364 0.172 -0.0108 -0.0498
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. When I run the code, I get warnings like:                        In check.distribution(.beta, .do.norm, .laplace) : 
  Warning! Sum of the input vector is NOT equal to 1. Function may produce incorrect results.  To fix this try to set .do.norm = TRUE in the function's parameters.

Comment: @user10193929 that would be an issue with the data showed instead of the comparison.  Here, you are using random values

Comment: Got it, thanks. Also, pardon my ignorance but why -1 for summarize_at

Comment: @user10193929 here, the first column in each list element is 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', so I am removing that to loop over the other columns and then do the cosinesimilarity with that first column

Comment: Some additional issue, if now I were to compute cosine similarity between Column A and all the names not starting with A, and similarly Column B and all the names not starting with B, how would I go about it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user10193929 can you please post as a new question as this may need some changes

Comment: @user10193929 added a solutiono